# Color on a scatter graph Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I have two variables I want to plot on a scatter graph. I want one variable to be displayed in blue and the other in red. I only just started using Python, and I am rather confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scatter` takes an argument `color` which allows you to set the point color (hard to guess).

```
x = linspace(0,10)
y1 = randn(50)
y2 = randn(50)+10

scatter(x, y1, color='red')
scatter(x, y2, color='blue')
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(10)
y = x
z = x*2
plt.scatter(x,y,c="r")
plt.scatter(x,z,c="b")
plt.show()
```

Have a read of [this](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) and the matplotlib docs in general.